# How can I fix the problems ($convergence=10 and $gradient=15) for longitudinal data (and random effects) using OPTIM in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate parameters from longitudinal data (y) where random effects are used as a part of the mean of y. The random effects follows bivariate normal distribution. While using optim in r, different methods are providing different results.

```
library(JM)
library(MASS)
library(survival)
library(splines)
library(nlme)
library(mvtnorm)
```

### data:

```
data("aids")
aids<-na.omit(aids)
aids<-aids[order(aids$Time),]
aids=aids[aids$patient %in% c(1:11), c("patient", "CD4",
  "obstime","Time","death","drug")]
delta<-aids$death
tv<-aids$Time
Zmat<-cbind(rep(1,length(delta)),aids$obstime)
aids$trt=as.numeric(aids$drug=="ddI")
Xmat<-cbind(rep(1,length(delta)),aids$obstime, aids$trt*aids$obstime)
Wmat=cbind(aids$trt)
y=aids$CD4
n=length(delta)
k=length(unique(aids$patient))
```

### created function to use in optim

```
p_y_hat=function(par,y,Xmat,Zmat){
  v.beta=par[1:3]
  v.sigma=par[4]
  mu=c(0,0)
  v.s=matrix(c(par[5],par[6],par[6],par[7]),2,2)
  b=mvrnorm(k,mu,v.s)
  m=drop(Xmat %*% v.beta + rowSums(Zmat * b[aids$patient, ]))
  return(dnorm(y,m,v.sigma))
}

m.LL1<-function(par,y,Xmat,Zmat) {
  LL1.pr<-p_y_hat(par,y,Xmat,Zmat)
  return( - sum(log(LL1.pr) ))
}
```

### bydefault optim method

```
fit1<-optim(par=c(1,0.2,0.2,5,2,1,3),m.LL1,
            control=list(maxit=1000),y=y,Xmat=Xmat,Zmat=Zmat)
```

which provides

```
> fit1

$par  
[1] 1.2277439 0.2643519 0.2702051 5.2276476 1.9062541 0.9728032 2.8033234    
$value    
[1] 102.8805    
$counts    
function gradient     
     853       NA     
$convergence
[1] 10
$message
NULL
```

### L-BFGS-B approach

```
    fit1<-optim(par=c(1,0.2,0.2,5,2,1,3),m.LL1,
  method="L-BFGS-B",control=list(maxit=1000),y=y,Xmat=Xmat,Zmat=Zmat)

$par
[1] 1.07742647 0.47206512 0.04462127 5.09672419 2.03116102 1.15173075 3.06604291
$value
[1] 305.7507
$counts
function gradient 
      15       15 
$convergence
[1] 0
$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

I am little bit confused about the correct method. The first one gave $convergence=10 (which is supposed to be wrong) and the second one gave $convergence=0 but $gradient=15 with some additional message.

Which method will be appropriate to estimate the parameters from the above longitudinal and bivariate normal distribution problem?

Answer (score 0):

`L-BFGS-B` thinks everything is fine (convergence code=0); the "gradient=15" you see there just denotes the number of times the gradient was evaluated.  The message ("CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F ...") is giving you extra information on *how* convergence was reached (L-BFGS-B uses multiple criteria), but you don't need to worry about it.

using the default (Nelder-Mead) optimizer, `optim()` reports that "degeneracy of the Nelder-Mead simplex" (see `?optim`), i.e. the region of parameter space that `optim()` is using to search for the optimum has collapsed to a lower dimension. Don't use this one.

As always, you should evaluate your results to make sure they make sense in the context of your problem ...

**note**: I'm only answering the narrow question posed here.  I haven't actually inspected your code to see if it's sensible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Ben. I actually wanted to know, while estimating the parameters from bivariate normal distribution whether I need to provide any condition (in the function created above) for constraint optimization OR I can directly use optim function to estimate parameters as I have done in the above example.